# How to disable ViewPager scrolling on diagonal swipes in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager

[image: Sketch that tries to explain what I mean]

I have an `Activity` with a `ViewPager`, which hosts several pages, each containing a `RecyclerView`. Horizontal and vertical swipes are working as expected: Horizontal changes the page, vertical scrolls the `RecyclerView`.

When the user makes a diagonal swipe, the page changes.

How can I prevent this? Diagonal swipes should only scroll the `RecyclerView`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/page"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

I already tried this:

```kotlin
binding.page.setOnTouchListener(object : View.OnTouchListener {
   override fun onTouch(v: View?, event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
      when (event?.action) {
         MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> binding.page.isUserInputEnabled = false
      }
      return v?.onTouchEvent(event) ?: true
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tested out the behavior you described. In my opinion `ViewPager2` and `RecyclerView` work together flawlessly:
On a diagonal swipe with less than 45°, the `ViewPager2` gets scrolled.
On diagonal swipes with more than 45°, the `RecyclerView` gets scrolled.

However, this seems only true when the `Activity` is newly created. It also seems to depend a little bit on the prior scroll gesture.

- When you first make a vertical swipe (`RecyclerView` gets scrolled), after that, diagonal scrolls again will scroll the `RecyclerView`.
- When you just made a horizontal swipe (`ViewPager2` gets scrolled), then diagonal scrolls tend to scroll the `ViewPager2`.

Maybe this is the intended behavior. To provide a more intuitive user experience,
I'd probably keep it as is, as I had to test quite some time to reproduce your described behavior.
Actually, all the scrolling felt very intuitive the way it is.

And keep in mind: If you really only want to allow exactly 0° horizontal swipes to scroll the `ViewPager2`, you're giving your users a very hard time.
It would be practically impossible to scroll the `ViewPager2`.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem than you, but in my case, I have a webView inside of my Fragment of my ViewPage than I make a test if the scroll was more vertical then horizontal and disable the user interaction of ViewPager if the was horizontal.

But look, this gestureDetector was applied to my WebView.

Like this

```
val gestureDetector =
        GestureDetector(
            context,
            object : GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                var initialValue = true

                override fun onDown(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
                    magazineViewActivity.mViewPagerMagazine?.isUserInputEnabled = true
                    initialValue = true
                    return super.onDown(e)
                }

                override fun onScroll(
                    e1: MotionEvent?,
                    e2: MotionEvent,
                    distanceX: Float,
                    distanceY: Float
                ): Boolean {
                    if(initialValue && Math.abs(distanceY) > Math.abs(distanceX)){
                        magazineViewActivity.mViewPagerMagazine?.isUserInputEnabled = false
                    }
                    initialValue = false

                    return super.onScroll(e1, e2, distanceX, distanceY)
                }
            },
        )
```